# On motivation for symplectic topology

Tags: symplectic-geometry, symplectic-linear-algebra

I am going to do my degree's dissertation, my advisor suggested I should start reading: "Introduction to symplectic topology" by McDuff and Salamon.

Actually, I find this book very interesting, but I still wonder what's the motivation for symplectic topology. It seems very restrictive and ungeneral so it is hard for me to understand what is the motivation for symplectic topology?

The book talks about how symplectomorphism preserve the solution of hamiltonian system(that if $z$ satisfies $\mathcal{J}_0\dot{z}=\nabla_tH(z)$ and $\psi$ is a symplectomorphism then 
if $z(t)=\phi(\eta(t))$, it follows that $\mathcal{J}_0\dot{\eta}=\nabla_t(H\psi(z))$)

However, then the book goes into detail into seemly unrelated topics, like masolv index, symplectic balls and non-squeezing, symplectic manifolds and what-not.

> So my question is, what is the relation between this and by is symplectic geometry/topology so important and what is it's motivation and its raison-d'être? What do symplectic manifolds have to do with hamiltonian systems?

Thanks to everyone

Comment: This is a very big question, which would deserve a very long answer, so I'll only comment on it. Symplectic geometry has its roots in Hamiltonian mechanics, as it was noticed that the phase spaces of usual mechanical systems are symplectic manifolds, and that Hamilton's equations can be understood as the ODE describing the integral curves of the (symplectic) gradient vector field associated to the (Hamiltonian) function of the system. Arnold's *Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics* is a good place to look for an elaboration of this relation.

Comment: Concerning the (lack of) generality of symplectic geometry: given any smooth manifold $Q$, its cotangent space $M=T^*Q$ is canonically a symplectic manifold, any diffeomorphism of $Q$ corresponds to a symplectomorphism of $M$, any submanifold of $Q$ correspond to a Lagrangian submanifold of $M$ (via its conormal bundle), any Riemannian metric on $Q$ corresponds to a function on $M$, etc. This suggests that differential geometry/topology canonically 'embed' into symplectic geometry/topology. Hence symplectic topology is not less general than differential topology; it's intertwined with it.

Comment: @JordanPayette Thank you very much for your comment. I'm just starting to learn more advanced differential geometry and I didn't know this properties of the cotangent bundle. Also I appreciate very much your book recomendation

Comment: If you are not familiar with manifold theory, fiber bundles and the basics of differential topology, you will probably find difficult to reach the end of chapter 2 in McDuff-Salamon's book, and to read the subsequent fundational chapters. The first part of Arnold's book is more concerned with physical systems; in the second part, as he aims to explain how all this is related to symplectic geometry, he first gives some quick introduction to manifolds and differential exterior forms.